# How to replace one item with another in itemize?

Tags: beamer, itemize

I have a simple itemize list in beamer. I want to replace the second item with an alternative version at the next transition.  Here is my minimal, not quite working, example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item <1->Line one
\item <2> First version of line 2
\item <3> Second version of line 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I also don't want to see the greyed out version of the second version of line 2 at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer has the `\alt` macro to provide alternative texts based on the current overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item <1-> Line one
\item <2-> \alt<3>{Second version of line 2}{First version of line 2}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't show the first version of line 2 greyed out.

Comment: @Simd see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Use `\only`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item <1->Line one
\only<2>{\item First version of line 2}
\only<3>{\item Second version of line 2}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: without any gray line]

or

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item <1->Line one
\only<1-2>{\item<2> First version of line 2}
\only<3>{\item Second version of line 2}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: with second item gray at step 1]

Comment: Your second version is perfect. The first one doesn't show the second line greyed out.

Comment: @Simd Wasn't sure, which result you wanted, so I've shown both. Maybe another user is interested in the first version.

Comment: Thank you very much.